# Force TimeZone in C# application

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

Is there a way to force C# application to use different timezone than one, received from Windows?

Preferably through settings (app.config, ...) or some block of code on initialization. Global replacement of usages like .ToLocalTime() or DateTime.Now is highly undesirable as number of such usages in project is 1000+.

I tried to play with TimeZone and TimeZoneInfo private fields, overriding stored TimeZone data but I don't know how to catch system calls inside of private class.

Comment: Problem is same. But recommended solution would require global changes in code that I am trying to avoid due to its size.

Comment: Just write extension method for `DateTime`, call it to example `ToLocalTimeMy()` and use search-and-replace function.

Comment: This will be my solution if nothing other will be found.

Answer (score -1):

DateTime has a `UTCNow` which retuns the UTC version of `Now` from UTC you can calculate any timezone with .AddHours(...)